# Python Built-in Map and Zip function in QGIS 2.0 Processing Script--syntax error

Tags: qgis, python

I am attempting to run my Python script using the Processing Toolbox in QGIS 2.0. I've used the built-in Python function map() and zip() several times and am now receiving a syntax error even though these functions worked fine in python console. Thanks in advance.

*I was asked to post a little more of my code, so i've edited and added a different chunk as I don't run into these errors when loading the vector layers by pathname…This makes me wonder if there's something wrong with the way these layers input into the Processing script. Mahalo:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from processing.core.VectorWriter import VectorWriter
import numpy
import processing

##input1=vector
##input2=vector
##Attribut=field input1
##output=output file

indivLayer = processing.getobject(input1)
grosLayer = processing.getobject(input2)

indivprovider = indivLayer.dataProvider()
grosprovider = grosLayer.dataProvider()

#Break grosLayer dictionary into list of lists (keys represent names of zones)
for key in CG_IDdict.keys():
    listofzones = CG_IDdict.values()

#Get sum of list of zones and put in dictionary with CG_ID keys
sumList = map(sum, listofzones)
sumdict = dict(zip(CG_IDlist, sumList)
#Count in zone
countList = map(len, listofzones)
#Get max and min value of zones
maxValue = map(max, listofzones)
minValue = map(min, listofzones)
#Get average value
meanValue = map(numpy.mean, listofzones)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Documents and Settings\user/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 150, in execute
self.processAlgorithm(progress)
File "C:\Documents and Settings\user/.qgis2/python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 213, in processAlgorithm
exec(script) in ns
File "<string>", line 74
countList = map(len, listofzones)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback as well as the script, if possible.

Comment: **PLEASE** include the actual error message. And at this point your code and the question don't even match up, there is no `map()` call whatsoever there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not close the paren on the line before.

```
sumdict = dict(zip(CG_IDlist, sumList)
```

should be

```
sumdict = dict(zip(CG_IDlist, sumList))
```